# Trying To Use Inline JS variable in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

I am trying to use the variable count that keeps track of page refreshes in the tag h1 but the actual value is not being used.H1 renders some data received from an express server. So I access the data at the index being the reload count.

```
script.
  var state = history.state || {};
  var reloadCount = state.reloadCount || 0;
  if (performance.navigation.type === 1) { // Reload
    state.reloadCount = ++reloadCount;
    history.replaceState(state, null, document.URL);
  } else if (reloadCount) {
    delete state.reloadCount;
    reloadCount = 0;
    history.replaceState(state, null, document.URL);
  }
  if (reloadCount >= 2) {
    // Now, do whatever you want...
    console.log("Hello");
    //alert('The page was reloaded more than twice!');
  }
body
 h1 #{data[reloadCount].text}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing up two different things here: client-side JS (the script tag at the beginning of your snippet) and server-side JS (in the Pug, evaluated in the `h1` statement). The content of the `h1` tag is evaluated *at compile-time*, so on the server, without knowledge of the value of `reloadCount`. There is no interaction whatsoever with the content in the `script.` tag, because that is just copied over as plain text to the output HTML by Pug. If you want to dynamically update something on the client-side (in the browser), you need to use client side JS to set the value of that `h1` element.